# Checking if a role in state matches the required in a comma seperated list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have this vuex state

```
const state = {
    clientSide:{
        iata:'',
        currencyrates:''
    },
    auth:{
        userid:'',
        token_string:'',
        full_names:'',
        email:'',
        role:'',
        loggedin_status:'',
        language:'en',
        currency:'USD',
        application_name:''
    }
};

export default state
```

that i am updating like this

```
this.$store.state.auth = response.data;
```

after successful authentication. I set into the state data like this

```
{"userid":"6373773738","token_string":"$2y$13$8kBYlKQz5.w3l0JRkMat8uL7nEW5Zxb4LUrxahVAIrNzPZDQDv1zO","full_names":"Josh Does","email":"account@gmail.com","role":"admin","loggedin_status":"loggedin","language":"string","currency":"USD","application_name":"box_overflow"}
```

I want to to make sure, a user can visit only routes allowed in his/her role and this are some of the routes

```
{
    path: '/view-review',
    name: 'view-review',
    meta: { title: 'View Review', requiresAuth: true, rolesAllowed: 'guest,admin,marketer', loginPage: '/user_login' },
    component: () => import('../views/View_Review.vue')
  },
  
    {
    path: '/write-review',
    name: 'view-review',
    meta: { title: 'Write Review', requiresAuth: true, rolesAllowed: 'end_user,admin,marketer',  loginPage: '/staff_login' },
    component: () => import('../views/Write_Review.vue')
  },
```

In my router

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

document.title = to.meta.title
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.state.auth.loggedin_status === 'loggedin' && store.state.auth.role is_in  record.meta.rolesAllowed) {
        
      next();
      return;
    }
    window.location.replace(record.meta.loginPage);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Does vue router have the ability to check if a role exists in a comma seperated list of allowed roles,for instance like in the pseudocode below

```
store.state.auth.loggedin === 'loggedin' && store.state.auth.role is_in  record.meta.rolesAllowed
```

Comment: Do you ask how implement this: `store.state.auth.role is_in  record.meta.rolesAllowed` or if Vue Router has permission check built-in?

Comment: If it can take a role and checks if it exists. Something similar to `FIND_IN_SET` in mysql, ref https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_find_in_set or `if (store.state.auth.loggedin === 'loggedin' && record.meta.rolesAllowed.indexOf(store.state.auth.role))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert list of roles into an array first and then iterate over looking for given role.

```
record.meta.rolesAllowed
   .split(',') // convert string to array by ',' char
   .includes(store.state.auth.role) // check if given role is in array
```

If `record.meta.rolesAllowed` is rather long you can convert it to `Set` before and call `has(store.state.auth.role)` instead.